# On an Ember 2.5.0, how can I transition to an error template without changing the URL?

Tags: ember.js

For reasons which are not important, sometimes our backend server will fail.

For both refreshing the page and requesting support, it would be useful for our application NOT to change the URL in the browser's address bar.

I've tried the following WITHOUT success:

```
const handleError = reason => {
  let windowLocation = window.location.href
  this.replaceRoute('error', new Ember.Error(reason));
  window.history.pushState(page, title, windowLocation);
};
```

Any suggestions which might work better?

Comment: The error sub-route is only triggered when the model hook returns a rejected promise, you could handle it there (prevent it from returning a rejected promise)

Comment: Thanks for the response... To be honest, I'm not entirely clear how I would use that information, but I found a solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was:

```
const handleError = () => this.intermediateTransitionTo('error');
```